# Capturing and formatting cout

Tags: c++

How can I capture the input of cout?

Example:

if I enter:

```
std::cout<<"Some normal text here" << fout <<"Test %, %", 1, 2<< "works 100% fine."<<std::endl
```

then it would print:

> "Some normal text here Test 1, 2 works 100% fine."

The 100% isn't formatted because of the << operator. Only things directly after the fout would be formatted until it met the << operator.

Can I do that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


std::ostream& fout (std::ostream& I)
{
    //Some how format my text here.. Then return it as the ostream.
    return I;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{    
    std::cout<< fout << "Test %", 1 << "Other stuff 20%.";
    //So Anything after fout<< should be stolen and formatted then given back to cout.. Other stuff 20% isn't formatted because of the <<.
}
```

I know it seems silly but I really want to know how it's done. I saw that boost does something similar by doing Format("%20") % SomeVar

But I want to figure out how to do it with the insertion operator and using the comma operator. Any ideas or anything similar?

Comment: Note that you'd have to do `<< (fout << "Test %", 1) <<` for this to work like you want it to. The comma operator has lower precedence.

Comment: That's ok. I wouldn't mind doing that but how? Am I capturing the ostream correctly? I can't seem to get the data in it. How would that work with the comma operator? Combining the comma and insertion is what I cannot figure out.

Comment: I think having `fout` return a type that can be implicitly cast to a string would work. You can use that type with a custom `operator,` overload to grab the previous string each time and fill it in, and then rely on the implicit conversion to a string, or overload `operator<<` for it as well.

Comment: By the way, I'm not saying this is the best that you can do, but it seems to work: http://liveworkspace.org/code/2YGlRc%244

Comment: Excellent! I like that one. I came up with something similar but I was using Fout() to construct an object so I looked up singletons in C++ and did it that way but seeing yours.. I will certainly change it to yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to define a new type for your `<<` and `,` operators to uniquely work on.

Something like this.

```
struct fout
{
    // To establish the formatting string (returns *this)
    fout& operator << ( const std::string &format_string );

    // To insert data into the formatted string (returns *this)
    template < typename T >
    fout& operator , ( const T &data );

    // To produce a type that can be sent to std::cout, etc.
    operator std::string ();
};
```

This would allow code like this:

```
cout << "Normal text " << (fout() << "Test %, %", 1, 2 ) << "works";
//                             ^^ A fout object is being constructed here.
```

If you don't like those parenthesis, rename the struct and create a single instance called `fout`.

Comment: Do i miss something? I could not compile it on g++ 4.7

Comment: @gongzhitaao Perhaps?  With an `#include<string>` and an `int main(){}` it compiles at ideone.com